# Selecting elements from nested list based on condition

Tags: list-manipulation

Assume that I have a nested list of the form

```
d = 0.1;
v = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1, d}, {y, -1, 1, d}, {z, -1, 1, d}];
```

How do I select all elements {x,y,z} of this list that satisfy the condition x^2+y^2+z^2≤1?

In my search for possible implementations I've come across similar questions that have been answered using either "Select[]", "Extract[]", or "Cases[]", but even after looking at their documentations I just cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res=    
  Join @@@ (v /. {a_, b_, c_} /; a^2 + b^2 + c^2 > 1 :> Nothing)
```

Proof

```
And @@ (#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 <= 1 & @@@ Flatten[res, 1])
```

True

**To answer the comment:**

```
flat = Flatten[res, 1]
```

(* outputs 4169 triples *)

**Addendum**

As a oneliner with the desired flatness:

```
Cases[#, {__Real}, -1] & @
 ReplaceAll[{a_, b_, c_} /; a^2 + b^2 + c^2 > 1 :> Nothing] @ v
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get this result in a list that is nested such that res={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},...} without any other nestings/brackets separating the three-element lists?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Would you mind explaining the meaning of "a_Real" (i.e. why not just "a_")? Also, what is the meaning of the parenthesis with ":>"?

Comment: `a_Real` wasn't necessary, so I deleted it (good observation). `:>` stands for `RuleDelayed` (see Documentation)

Comment: OK, great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> using either "Extract[]"

to use Extract, you need to give `Position`

```
pred[{x_,y_,z_}] := x^2+y^2+z^2<=1;
d = 0.1;
v = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1, d}, {y, -1, 1, d}, {z, -1, 1, d}] // Flatten[#,2]&;
v // Extract[v // Position[_?pred]] // Length
```

> 4169

Answer (score 3):

Alternative view:

```
(pts = CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
    0.1]) // Dimensions

(ptsInside = 
   Select[Flatten[pts, 2], RegionMember[Ball[]]]) // Dimensions

Show[ListPointPlot3D[ptsInside, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
 , Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[0.3, Yellow], Ball[]
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> using either "Select[]"

step by step

select all elements **{x,y,z}** satisfy the condition **x^2+y^2+z^2≤1**?

```
pred[{x_,y_,z_}] := x^2+y^2+z^2<=1;
```

then we need to make the list `{p1, p2, ...}`, so `//Flatten[#,2]&;`

which gives

```
pred[{x_,y_,z_}] := x^2+y^2+z^2<=1;
d = 0.1;
v = Table[{x, y, z}, {x, -1, 1, d}, {y, -1, 1, d}, {z, -1, 1, d}] // Flatten[#,2]&;
v // Select[pred] // Length
```

> 4169